# Behaviuor of HTTP POST request on JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I recorded a scenario in Jmeter 
My Question is I am using POST request in 2 places
1. Login
2. Adding some details and save

I am also using HTTP Cookie Manager
I have verified that I logged in successfully and in respond tab I also got that user got to home page from login page

For Adding details I use correlation and it is also working fine(Checked by Debug Sampler)

What is happening if I am adding e.g Name, mobile No from a Form and replay I am getting same page in Response TAB(Checked in View Result Tree)

In my opinion it should display Success Page which render after adding the details

For Success page JMeter Recording a New sample which come next the POST request sample for Adding page

Is this the right behavior of Jmeter

Comment: Can you share your jmx file?

Comment: I can share but it will not execute other than internal QA envoirment.

Comment: Can you check if the response has multiple redirects? Also verify the correctness of script by checking if the entries are made in DB/UI.

Comment: How to verify for multiple redirects..I am new in Jmeter ...entries are not happening while replaying the script

Comment: @ sjmach..I have no idea how to attach a file here...please guide else please share email id , I will email